# Can we have multiple packages with the same name in different namespaces?

Tags: tcl

I am confusing with package and namespace concept TCL comparing with other Languages .

Can anyone clear me the question  Can we have multiple packages with the same name in different namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the 'have' in your question as 'use', the answer is No. The package mechanism looks up packages in a database where each package name is unique. It is a useful convention to put things that go in the Foo package in the namespace Foo, but the namespace has no effect on package lookup. That said, I believe you can put different *versions* of a package in different namespaces, but you can still only use one version at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one version of a package in an interpreter at a time. Packages are identified by their name, and this is entirely independent of what namespace(s) they use. You could do tricks with loading different versions into different interpreters in the same process (you'll need `interp create` and the `-exact` flag to `package require` to pick up precise versions rather than the “best” one) but that's going to be really horrible to work with.

If you've got code that it makes sense to have multiple instances active of at once in the same interpreter, the package should actually initially define a factory for those instances. Consider using classes (see [incr Tcl], XOTcl, TclOO, Snit, …)

Comment: The trick with loading different versions in different interpreters is actually used by the tcllib pluginmgr package.

Comment: @schlenk That way lies madness (as I know from the tangle I've seen happen in Java…)